# Trying to upsert a table with partial index

Tags: postgresql, upsert, postgresql-9.5

So I have a table with structure similar to:

```
CREATE TABLE x (
    id SERIAL,
    a character varying(1024) NOT NULL,
    b character varying(2048),
    c character varying(1024)
);

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX uniq_x_a ON x USING btree (a) WHERE (b IS NULL);
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX uniq_x_a_b ON x USING btree (a, b) WHERE (b IS NOT NULL);
```

Now I upgraded this instance to 9.5 and want to use the `ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE`.

So executing this

```
INSERT INTO x (a, b, c) VALUES ('hello', 'there', 'c1');
INSERT INTO x (a, b, c) VALUES ('hello', 'there', 'c2');
```

now gives me

```
ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "uniq_x_a_b"
DETAIL:  Key (a, b)=(hello, there) already exists.
```

Then when I do

```
INSERT INTO x (a, b, c) VALUES ('hello', 'there', 'c4') 
ON CONFLICT ON CONSTRAINT uniq_x_a_b DO UPDATE SET c = excluded.c;
```

I get

```
ERROR:  constraint "uniq_x_a_b" for table "x" does not exist
```

I don't understand, I'm violating a non existing constraint? Anybody has a tip?

**Edit**

Per suggestion I added

```
ALTER TABLE x ADD CONSTRAINT uniq_x_a_b_constraint UNIQUE (a, b);
```

So this now works for the following case:

```
INSERT INTO x (a, b, c) VALUES ('hello', 'there', 'c3') 
ON CONFLICT ON CONSTRAINT uniq_x_a_b_constraint DO UPDATE SET c = excluded.c;
```

But fails for

```
INSERT INTO x (a, b, c) VALUES ('hello', NULL, 'c3') 
ON CONFLICT ON CONSTRAINT uniq_x_a_b_constraint DO UPDATE SET c = excluded.c;
```

with

```
ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "uniq_x_a"
DETAIL:  Key (a)=(hello) already exists.
```

And I can't add a unique constraint on column `a` alone because it's the combination of `a` and `b` that is supposed to be unique. It also seems impossible to construct a constraint on a subset of the rows like it's possible with creating an index.

Answer (score 3):

There is a couple of things at play here.

1. Creating a unique index doesn't automatically create a unique constraint (despite the term `constraint` being used in the error message when you tried to insert duplicate records).  On the other hand, adding a unique constraint will automatically create a unique B-tree index on the column or group of columns (see this [doc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-constraints.html)).
2. Unlike in the case of regular indexes, constraints cannot be added using partial indexes:

   ```
   ALTER TABLE x ADD CONSTRAINT uniq_x_a_constraint UNIQUE USING INDEX uniq_x_a;
   ERROR:  "uniq_x_a" is a partial index ...
   DETAIL:  Cannot create a primary key or unique constraint using such an index.
   ```

In essence, you'll need to create a separate unique constraint on `(a, b)` (unrelated to the partial indexes) in order to make `ON CONFLICT` function in the expected way.

[UPDATE]

Even though combination of a and b is unique, `ON CONFLICT` won't see any valid constraint enforcing the uniqueness:

```
INSERT INTO x (a, b, c) VALUES ('hello', 'there', 'c4') 
ON CONFLICT (a, b) DO UPDATE SET c = excluded.c;
ERROR:  there is no unique or exclusion constraint matching the ON CONFLICT specification
```

Now, if you add a constraint, both `ON CONFLICT (a, b)` and `ON CONFLICT ON CONSTRAINT` will work:

```
ALTER TABLE x ADD CONSTRAINT uniq_x_a_b_constraint UNIQUE (a, b);

INSERT INTO x (a, b, c) VALUES ('hello', 'there', 'c4') 
ON CONFLICT (a, b) DO UPDATE SET c = excluded.c;

INSERT INTO x (a, b, c) VALUES ('hello', 'there', 'c5') 
ON CONFLICT ON CONSTRAINT uniq_x_a_b_constraint DO UPDATE SET c = excluded.c;
```

Comment: the combination of a and b is supposed to be unique, only b can can contain NULL values.

Comment: @Jan, Please see my expanded answer.

Comment: yes, but this fails on `INSERT INTO x (a, b, c) VALUES ('hello', NULL, 'c3') ON CONFLICT ON CONSTRAINT uniq_x_a_b_constraint DO UPDATE SET c = excluded.c;`

Comment: Interesting observation.  It seems to me UPSERT fails because there isn't a `(a, b is null)` constraint for `ON CONFLICT` to act on before PostgreSQL enforces partial index `uniq_x_a`'s uniqueness.  I would also expect that `uniq_x_a_b_constraint` should allow `ON CONFLICT` to apply even when `b` is null.  I suppose if PostgreSQL supports partial constraints like it does for partial indexes, we would be able to handle this case.  @Jan, thank you for the question, which reveals interesting issues in using UPSERT with partial indexes.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I planned to refactor my code to make the empty string the default for the `b` column. That should remove the need for a partial constraint or index.

Comment: That sounds to me a wise move, given the revealed limitation of using UPSERT with partial indexes.